# what is the neat way to divide huge nested loops to 8(or more) processes using Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

this time i'm facing a "design" problem. Using Python, I have a implement a mathematical algorithm which uses 5 parameters. To find the best combination of these 5 parameters, i used 5-layer nested loop to enumerate all possible combinations in a given range. The time it takes to finish appeared to be beyond my expectation. So I think it's the time to use multithreading...

The task in the core of nested loops are calculation and saving. In current code, result from every calculation is appended to a list and the list will be written to a file at the end of program.

since I don't have too much experience of multithreading in any language, not to mention Python, I would like to ask for some hints on what should the structure be for this problem. Namely, how should the calculations be assigned to the threads dynamically and how should the threads save results and later combine all results into one file. I hope the number of threads can be adjustable.

Any illustration with code will be very helpful.

thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it.

#

update of 2nd Day:
thanks for all helpful answers, now I know that it is multiprocessing instead of multithreading. I always confuse with these two concepts because I think if it is multithreaded then the OS will automatically use multiple processor to run it when available. 
I will find time to have some hands-on with multiprocessing tonight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using [jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug), a library I wrote for very similar problems. Your code would then look something like

```
from jug import TaskGenerator
evaluate = TaskGenerator(evaluate)

for p0 in [1,2,3]:
    for p1 in xrange(10):
        for p2 in xrange(10,20):
             for p3 in [True, False]:
                for p4 in xrange(100):
                    results.append(evaluate(p0,p1,p2,p3,p4))
```

Now you could run as many processes as you'd like (even across a network if you have access to a computer cluster).

Comment: wow this looks sexy, 'cause it's very similar to my current structure. let's see how jug rocks...  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add to this answer that you're the author of this library, as per http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion

Comment: Hi Luis, I tried your code snippet on a 2-core machine, however it seems only around 50% CPU is used, I checked the processes list in task manager(Windows), python.exe has that 50% for sure, but it has only 1 thread. I there some additional settings?  thanks again!

Comment: Run two processes simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry for the curt response, but for long-form support email me or jug-users [http://groups.google.com/group/jug-users] (or post a separate stackoverflow question).

Comment: Hi, Luis, I was trying to figure out how to run two processes simultaneously... but not really got it.  please refer to my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589030/with-jug-how-to-run-nested-loops-in-multiprocessing-mode)

Answer (score 7):

Multithreading in Python won't win you anything in this kind of problem, since Python doesn't execute threads in parallel (it uses them for I/O concurrency, mostly).

You want `multiprocessing` instead, or a friendly wrapper for it such as [joblib](http://packages.python.org/joblib/):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

# -1 == use all available processors
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(evaluate)(x) for x in enum_combinations())
print best_of(results)
```

Where `enum_combinations` would enumerate all combinations of your five parameters; you can likely implement it by putting a `yield` at the bottom of your nested loop.

joblib distributes the combinations over multiple worker processes, taking care of some load balancing.

Comment: strange, I tried this one:  Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(sqrt)(i**2) for i in range(10000))  it's fine. but when I change n_jobs=2 or -1, then thousands processes are created and job is never done. the machine is ended up by restarting...   where is wrong?  i'm using a intel E6300 CPU  thanks

Comment: @Watt: I've never had any such problem with joblib. You might want to [file a bug report](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/new).

Comment: the same problem...  is joblib not for windows?

Comment: @Watt, if you're still interested (I see you accepted the jug-based answer): joblib has some issues on Windows, which apparently can be resolved by putting the above script in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a calculation-heavy problem (and thus CPU-bound), multi-*threading* won't help you much in Python due to the GIL.

What you can, however, do is split the calculation across multiple *processes* to take advantage of extra CPU cores. The easiest way to do this is with the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) library.

There are a number of examples for how to use `multiprocessing` on the docs page for it.

Comment: oh, i always mix multithreading with multiprocessing...  thanks!