# With Jug, how to run nested loops in multiprocessing mode?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

for example, the following code only run the task in 1 process:

```
from jug import TaskGenerator
evaluate = TaskGenerator(evaluate)

for p0 in [1,2,3]:
for p1 in xrange(10):
    for p2 in xrange(10,20):
         for p3 in [True, False]:
             for p4 in xrange(100):
                results.append(evaluate(p0,p1,p2,p3,p4))
```

where should I indicate the number of processes? 
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of [jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug) here.

To run this script, assuming it is a file called `script.py`,  you will run the `jug execute script.py` command (and not `python script.py`).

You can simply run multiple of these in parallel. If you are using a Unix-like shell, the following should work just fine in order to use two processors:

```
jug execute script.py &
jug execute script.py &
```

The different processes will communicate with each other using the file system to divide up the work (this is the default, you can also use a redis backend if you want to use a cluster of machines that do not share a file system).

You can also use the following to check on the progress while they run:

```
jug status script.py
```

Comment: ah, you mean like this. but will all the started script.py share the given parameter space?

Comment: Hi Luis, once again, I'm using IDLE and Eclipse on Win7, the "jug execute ..." command in the IDLE shell, saying syntax error. Where shall I type it in windows environment?  thanks again!

Comment: I know nothing about Windows or Eclipse, sorry.

Comment: @Watt: Run from the command line. Assuming `jug` has been added to the system path, you can simply hold down shift and right-click the folder containing your `script.py`, then select "Open Command Window here" or whatever it says (this only works on Vista and Win7 by default, but you have Win7 so it doesn't matter), then type `jug execute` and then whatever the name of your `py` file actually is.

Comment: Try `start /B jug execute script.py` to launch a background process (via http://superuser.com/a/345605/153528). Assuming `jug` is executable from the commandline. See JAB's answer to open a Windows commandline.