# Friendly wrapper for Multiprocessing on Windows7 in Python 2.6 environment?

Tags: python, windows-7, multiprocessing

For Python 2.6, is there a friendly wrapper for Multiprocessing that works in a Windows 7 environment?

On [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576515/what-is-the-neat-way-to-divide-huge-nested-loops-to-8or-more-processes-using-py) people helped me with similar knowledge for only Unix environment. But for my current project, it's already too late to shift the environment.

Comment: I was under the impression from the docs it works under Windows ("It runs on both Unix and Windows" - http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html). Have you tried it?

Comment: @SteveMc I think he was referring to a wrapper like [jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug). Seeing as it's hosted on [github](https://github.com/luispedro/jug) it should be 'reasonably' simple to port it to windows. Simple as in a lot easier than starting from scratch...

Answer (score 5):

Author of [jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug) here. I would still recommend it on Windows. If there is a reason it doesn't work, I can help you make the code platform-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at the new [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) library from the python 3.2 standardlib? (there is a [backport](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) availabe for older python versions).

Comment: Oh I like this, looks very similar to something I rolled  myself a while back, but a lot more refined, and with support for both threads and processes with the same interface. what versions of python have you used this under? Do the backports exhibit any differences? As much as jug loos interesting, this is part of the standard lib in python 3 so you might be winning the cookie... I might have to test these out at the weekend...

Comment: @BiggAl: I've only tried it out briefly with the backport under python 2.7. Whether the backports exhibit differences, I can't say for sure (but they're not supposed to, and there is no mention in the docs about differences)