# Optimizing a Nested loop that contains 8 for loops to minimize a function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python code that maximizes a function over 8 parameters using a nested for loop. It takes approximately 16 Minutes to execute which is way too much because I have to do the optimization numerous time for the problem I am trying to solve.

**I tried:**

1.) Replacing the for loop by list comprehension but there was no change in performance.

2.) [Jug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576515/what-is-the-neat-way-to-divide-huge-nested-loops-to-8or-more-processes-using-p) to parallize but the entire system freezes and restarts.

**My Questions:**

1.) Is there any other way to parallelize a nested for loop using multiprocessing module?

2.) Is there any way I can replace the nested loop with completely different method to maximize the function?

```
Code Snippet: 
def SvetMaxmization(): #Maximization function
    Max = 0
    res = 1.0 # Step Size, execution time grows expo if the value is reduced
    for a1 in np.arange(0, pi, res):
        for a2 in np.arange(0,pi, res):
            for b1 in np.arange(0,pi, res):
                for b2 in np.arange(0,pi, res):
                    for c1 in np.arange(0,pi, res): 
                        for c2 in np.arange(0,pi, res):
                            for d1 in np.arange(0,pi, res):
                                for d2 in np.arange(0,pi, res):
                                   present =Svet(a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2) #function to be maximized 
                                   if present > Max:
                                        Max = present
```

**svet() function:**

```
def Svet(a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2):
    Rho = Desnitystate(3,1) #Rho is a a matrix of dimension 4x4
    CHSH1 = tensor(S(a1),S(b1)) + tensor(S(a1),S(b2)) + tensor(S(a2),S(b1)) - tensor(S(a2),S(b2)) # S returns a matrix of dimension 2x2
    CHSH2 = tensor(S(a1),S(b1)) + tensor(S(a1),S(b2)) + tensor(S(a2),S(b1)) - tensor(S(a2),S(b2))
    SVet3x1 = tensor(CHSH1, S(c2)) + tensor(CHSH2, S(c1))
    SVet3x2 = tensor(CHSH2, S(c1)) + tensor(CHSH1, S(c2))                   
    SVet4x1 = tensor(SVet3x1, S(d2)) + tensor(SVet3x2, S(d1))           
    Svd = abs((SVet4x1*Rho).tr())

    return Svd
```

**System details: Intel Core I5 clocked at 3.2GHz**

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Does "the entire system freezes and restarts" mean that the program created too many threads/processes and/or allocated too much memory? It would be better if write it directly so others don't have to guess.

Comment: @max630 I am sorry I did not include that information because I am not sure why the system restarts.

Comment: Are all those parameters necessary? I think the best way for you to optimize performance is not by trying to increase the efficiency of the for loops but rather find a way to minimize the quantity of parameters.

Comment: Is the function locally smooth?    Could you do a comparatively coarse grained search (res = 10.0), 1. evaluate the function at each of the resulting points, 2. store the result and values for a1 to d2.  3. Sort by result.  4.  Ignore all but the ?10? best locations.  5.  Search at much higher resolution in the vicinity of those much locations.

Comment: Also, how expensive is np.arrange?  Is it worth saving the result into a local list, and using that in each for loop?

Comment: Final suggestion:  Recode in C++ (or even GPU code)?  Python is wonderful, but it wouldn't be my first choice for the core of an intensive numerical library.

Comment: Seems like you essentially try to generate 8 numbers in `np.arange(0, pi, res)`. If you do not want the loop, you could also try to generate the possible numbers in a function one by one actually (since it seems like counter actually). Then it will at least get rid of all your 8 loops.

Comment: What does the `Svet` function look like? Can you find its partial derivatives analytically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a single "right" answer, as it will depend a lot on the behaviour of your cost function.

But, considering that you are now doing a gridsearch over the parameter space (basically brute-forcing the solution), I think there are some things worth trying.

1. See if you can use a more sophisticated optimization algorithm.
   See the [`scipy.optimize` module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html), e.g. just if

   ```
   x0 = ... # something
   bounds = [(0,np.pi) for _ in range(len(x0))]
   result = minimize(Svet, x0, bounds=bounds)
   ```

   can solve the problem.
2. If the cost function is so badly behaved that none of those methods work, your only hope is probably to speed up the execution of the cost function itself. In my own experience, I would try the following:

   1. [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) is a good first alternative because it is very simple to try since it does not require you to change anything in your current code. It doesn't always speed up your code though.
   2. Rewrite the cost function with [`Cython`](http://cython.org/). This requires some work on your part, but will likely give a large boost in speed. Again, this depends on the nature of your cost function.
   3. Rewrite using e.g. C, C++, or any other "fast" language.

Comment: And if Python is the only choice of language, `values = np.arange(0, pi, res); for params in itertools.product(*[values]*8): Svet(*params)` will at least be faster than Python-level nested loops.

Comment: True, but the win is something like 40 ms total (I timed it using a dummy function) which is not really relevant when the total time is 16 minutes. It gives you *much* nicer code than 8 nested loops though. Which is a good reason enough to prefer it. Good comment!

Comment: You are correct! I only tested the parameter generation forgot OP's code took 16 minutes. So yes, in the grand scheme of things there is no speed gain. There might be tangible optimization within `Svet()`, but we can't say much without knowing what it looks like. Outside of that, I agree with the steps in your solution and I'm hopeful it shouldn't come down to a Python brute-force implementation.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for all the suggestions. I have added the Svet function to the question. The function implements lot of matrix multiplication like outer product and dot product, I know all these operations are very costly and there is no hope to improve the performance. I tried cython and numba but no luck. The only hope is to find a way to parallelize the nested for loop.

Comment: @HannesOvrén sorry for not upvoting, I dont have "Reputations" yet.